# Date validation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How to check if the date is valid date in ruby. Many of the methods are check only the range. But, I need to check the date with day of
week to check whether the date is valid or not. For Ex:

```
    20 Jul 2016 Wed --> Valid
    20 Jul 2016 Mon --> Not-Valid
```

How to do this in ruby ?

Comment: You get the date as a string or a Date Object

Comment: @SpunkyLive String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not pretend on the best solution ever, but this should work.

```
def valid_date?(date)
  Date.parse(date).strftime("%d %b %Y %a") == date
end

[55] pry(main)> valid_date?("20 Jul 2016 Wed")
=> true
[56] pry(main)> valid_date?("20 Jul 2016 Mon")
=> false
[57] pry(main)>
```

If you have many formats you may pass format as a second argument

```
def valid_date?(date, fmt)
  Date.parse(date).strftime(fmt) == date
end

=> :valid_date?
[59] pry(main)> valid_date?("20 Jul 2016 Wed", "%d %b %Y %a")
=> true
```

Hope this will help.

**UPDATE**

As I mentioned in comment that method name overlaps with existing method [valid_date?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-valid_date-3F)

So, you may just rename the custom method

```
def date_valid?(date, fmt)
  Date.parse(date).strftime(fmt) == date
end

[2] pry(main)> date_valid?("20 Jul 2016 Wed", "%d %b %Y %a")
=> true
```

Comment: It produce the following error. `d.rb:6:in valid_date?': wrong number of arguments (2 for 3..4) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Which Rails version do you use?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]

Comment: Ok, my fault it's overlaps with http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-valid_date-3F Please have a look on updated section.

Comment: Welcome :) Glad was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
dates = ['20 Jul 2016 Wed', '20 Jul 2016 Mon']
dates.map do |date|
  Date.parse(date).public_send(
    Date.instance_methods.detect do |m|
      m.to_s =~ /\A#{date[-3..-1].downcase}.*day\?\z/
    end)
end
#⇒ [ true, false ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

dates = ['20 Jul 2016 Wed', '20 Jul 2016 Mon']

dates.select do |s|
  d = Date.strptime(s[0,11], "%d %b %Y") rescue nil
  d.nil? ? false : (Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[d.wday] == s[-3,3])
end
  #=> ["20 Jul 2016 Wed"]
```

This reads, "select strings `'dd mmm yyyy'` that represent valid dates and whose day-of-week matches the day-of-week given by the last three characters of the string".